# Symfony 2 app_dev.php error

Tags: symfony

I have an error on when i go to my app_dev.php with other computer.

**Error 1 :**

> Notice: require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null] h->filename=[/var/www/trunk/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php] in /var/www/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1197

**Error 2 :**

> Notice: require(): apc_cache_find [1182224] in /var/www/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1197

**Error 3 :**

> Notice: require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null] h->filename=[/var/www/trunk/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php] in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php on line 55

**Error 4 :**

> Notice: require(): apc_cache_find [1051245] in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php on line 55 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message '

**Error 5 :**

> Notice: require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null] h->filename=[/var/www/trunk/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php] in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php line 55' in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:67

**Stack Trace :**

> **Stack trace: #0** 
>   /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php(55): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle(8, 'require(): 1. h...', '/var/www/trunk/...', 55, Array)
>
> **Stack trace: #1** /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php(55): Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugUniversalClassLoader::loadClass()
>
> **Stack trace: #2** [internal function]: Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugUniversalClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...')
>
> **Stack trace: #3** 
>   /var/www/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache(491): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Compone...')
>
> **Stack trace: #4** /var/www/trunk/ in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 67

On config.php, it's ok, and error 500 on app.php

How can i resolve this notice ?

Comment: How can i resolve this notice ?

Comment: Did you remove the cache (deleting everything within the cache/ directory)? Is this symfony 2.0 or 2.1? Are you using deps or composer? What where you doing prior to this error? Give us some background information!

Comment: I remove all the cache (via php console and deleting floder content). I deleting the content of the log folder. This is Synfony 2.0. Before, i just copy my website to a Debian server FROM Wamp Server (windows server 2008 R2). I using svn for this copy.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try `composer install` and `app/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo chown -R username:www-data main-dir/
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo rm -rf vendor
composer install
```